# jQuery show rows that meet criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with multiple tabs on it per region.

On page load, I load all of the data into a hidden table and when you click on a tab, it pulls in the table and filters the data (removes rows not needed for that tab).

For example, each `tr` in my table has classes on it with the region names.

`<tr class="americas emea apac"></tr>` <- this row falls into those 3 regions.

I have a tab for example that only shows me data for americas:

`$('#' + tab).find("#trainingEvents .results tr:not(.Americas)").remove();` This removes all rows from the table that do not have `americas` in the class.

My goal is to now make a condition where all 3 of them are required.

When I click "Global", the row must contain all 3 of the classes or it is removed from the table.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this? I was thinking about `contains` but that would be `true` if only one of them was met.

Comment: I think [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) would work

Comment: if you only need the one conditon can modify selector to : `tr:not(.americas.emea.apac)` but would use `filter()` also if it needs to be more dynamic

Comment: It must meet all 3 conditions. I only want to show rows that have all 3 classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to accomplish what you want:

```js
function filterTable(selector) {
 $("table tr").hide().filter(selector).show(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="americas emea apac">
    <td>americas emea apac</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="americas">
    <td>americas</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="americas emea">
    <td>americas emea</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="apac">
    <td>apac</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Americas" onclick="filterTable('.americas');" />
<input type="button" value="EMEA" onclick="filterTable('.emea');" />
<input type="button" value="APAC" onclick="filterTable('.apac');" />
<input type="button" value="Global" onclick="filterTable('.americas.emea.apac');" />
```

Comment: Is there a `not` condition in `filter` ? `$('#' + tab).find("#trainingEvents .results tr").filter('.Americas.EMEA.APAC').remove();` I want to remove all rows where this isn't true. Yours works fine with hiding them initially and then showing based on the filter but I need to remove the rows

Comment: Sure just replace .filter() with [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or use `.filter(':not(.Americas.EMEA.APAC)')`